# Matches share common whitespace issue

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

Long story short, I want to remove a word with corresponding whitespaces

**Need:**
`abc test test def` -> `abc def`

**But:**
`abc xtest xtest def` -> `abc xtest xtest def` (just to keep in mind)

**I tried:**

```
$ echo "abc test test def" | sed "s/\s\<test\>\s/ /g"
abc test def
```

So, if I apply this regex 2 times, I'll get what I need. But is there any way how to do it without *sed*'ding in loop?

[Matches share common whitespace pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQKCY.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo "abc test test def" | sed "s/\s\(\<test\>\s\)*/ /g"
```

=>abc def

```
echo "abc test test def test " | sed "s/\s\(\<test\>\s\)*/ /g"
```

=>abc def

This looks for a space `\s` followed by a possibly repeating group `\<test\>\s`
By looking for a group that repeats an indeterminate number of times, we can handle the case where there's only one `test` and also handle the special case where there are adjacent `test test`.

Comment: Works like a charm, nice hack. Thanks